# Obtaining array element differences in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string-matching

Say I have two string arrays:

```
String[] first = new String[]{"12","23","44","67"};
String[] second= new String[]{"12","22","46","67"};
```

I searched for a function like PHP's [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which will give me the difference of these two arrays like this:

```
{"23","44"}
```

Is there a in-built function for this operation, or should I create a for loop and check for the differences ?

Comment: no there is no built in function. you can create a comparator for that.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: You should consider using `List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("12", "23");` instead of `String[]`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann `Arrays.asList` returns a `List`, why would you pass this to a `List` constructor? Second, depending on the use case an array is a perfectly acceptable data structure.

Comment: If the second list was `"12","22","23","67"`, what would he diff be?

Comment: @JohnB Since it depends I was careful to use the word "consider". Similarly for `Arrays.asList`, the returned list implements some of the methods (e.g. `add()`) of the `List` interface by throwing an exception. I do not know the circumstances under which the OP wants to use the Strings and therefore choose the more flexible version.

Comment: instead of array r u interested in ArrayList?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create two Sets from these arrays, like:

```
List<String> firstList = Arrays.asList(first);
List<String> secondList = Arrays.asList(second);

Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>(first);
Set<String> secondSet = new HashSet<String>(second);
```

and then use the `removeAll` method:

```
firstSet.removeAll(secondList);
secondSet.removeAll(firstList);
```

so now `firstList` contains all the elements that are only available in the first array and `secondList` only the elements available in the second array.

A set that will contain only the elements available in one of the sets (without elements available in both sets) can be created using:

```
new HashSet<String>(firstSet).addAll(secondSet);
```

Comment: This code `Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>(first);` gives "Connot resolve constructor Hashset(java.lang.String[])" error. Can Hashset be constructed like this?

Answer (score 3):

Guava's `Sets` class has a [difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) method.

so

```
Set<String> diff = Sets.difference(newHashSet(first), newHashSet(second));
```

Comment: This link is better: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#difference(java.util.Set, java.util.Set)

Comment: I didn't know Guava, Also thank you for valuable library info.

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays are not arrays at all, that's why there is such weird method for diff.

If you want difference between two sets (A - B) in mathematical sense, then

1) use sets

```
Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>();
Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

2) use difference method (contains all elements in set1 that not in set2)

```
set1.removeAll(set2)
```

Note, this is assymetric difference.

Comment: Doesn't removeAll returns a boolean rather then set elements?

Comment: @trante Yes. But it also modifies set1 according to `set1 - set2`